# C# Outlook 2010 - Getting error when using 'this.Application'

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2010

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the following error?  Google has not been of much assistance.  Sorry this is kind of vague. The purpose of the code is to get all unread messages out of Outlook and into a C# form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestEmailGetter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = 
                this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
                (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Outlook.Items unreadItems = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");

            MessageBox.Show(
                string.Format("Unread items in Inbox = {0}", unreadItems.Count));
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR:'TestEmailGetter.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Application' and no extension method 'Application' accepting a first argument of type 'TestEmailGetter.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

The error is occuring on this line:

```
this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

I have no idea what to add to fix it. :-(

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm a total newbie at this.  So to clarify, I basically copy/pasted the code directly from the MSDN located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms268869.aspx
So I'm not sure why the code the Microsoft is giving out is not working.

Comment: I did take your advice and removed the {this} keyword, but then I just get different errors. Namely: Error 1 'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Application' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application' 

I'm confused. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your `Form1` class hasn't member `Application`. You must use it without `this` if you want to reference the static members of `Application` class from namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`.

**UPDATE**

Use `Outlook.Application`...

Comment: ı already add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.but it gives me error too..

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error do the following. You have to create a OutlookApplication object before you can use it in a standalone application.

```
Outlook.Application OutlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Folder calFolder =
   OutlookApplication.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
       Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
       as Outlook.Folder;
```